# VB Web Developer / SQL GETDATE()

Tags: sql, vb.net

So I am having a probem with an SQL Update Statement.

I am running it when a user logs in the following code runs:

```
Dim UpdateSQL As String 
UpdateSQL = "UPDATE tblUsers SET LoginDate = GETDATE()" 
UpdateSQL = UpdateSQL & " WHERE ID = '" & Session("ID") & "'"
```

the problem I think is with the `Session("ID")` part as when I explicitly call out what record to update that works just fine.

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: First: [SQL injection warning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!, second: Isn't your `ID` a numeric data type?

Comment: ID is type int. Its the Primary Key for the users in the table.

Comment: It would be helpful to include all of the code and also to include the error messages you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ID` is of type `int`, you should omit `'`:

```
UpdateSQL = UpdateSQL & " WHERE ID = " & Session("ID")
```

But be aware of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Additionally, maybe it's better not to use `Session("ID")`. I guess you get the `ID` while logging in the user. Store the value in a variable and use this variable in your query, not the session.

Comment: New Error now further down it wont run the command:
    myReader.Close()
    myCmdUp.ExecuteNonQuery() 'Error points to here saying Incorrect syntax near '='.
    MyConnection.Close()

Comment: Well, we even don't know your first error, you did not post any message.

Comment: Sorry keep hitting Enter and posting the comment. New to this whole thing :)

Comment: What was the first error? My guess is that your `Session("ID")` might be null.

Comment: Didn't return an error the first time, just the record did not update at all.